# readHTMLTable in R

Tags: html, r

I am trying to read an html table in R, and perform further analysis on it. I found readHTMLTable() in R. When I download the table I am interested in, and try to perform some analysis on it, I am given a reply that the vector is NULL, and am having troubles converting it to numeric so I can perform averages, and further calculations on. If anyone has any ideas to help, it would be great! I attach my code below.
Many thanks

Alex

```
a=readHTMLTable("http://www.nhl.com/ice/standings.htm?season=20132014&type=LEA",which=3,trim=F,colClasses)
summary(a)
a=droplevels(a)
summary(a)
```

Comment: I wanted to add this as well    a=readHTMLTable("http://www.nhl.com/ice/standings.htm?season=20132014&type=LEA",which=3,trim=F,colClasses) reads the table, and when I use    a$ROW I get NULL answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
require(XML)
appURL <- "http://www.nhl.com/ice/standings.htm?season=20132014&type=LEA"
xData <- htmlParse(appURL)
appStats <- readHTMLTable(xData['//table'][[3]])
> head(appStats)
    structure(c("p - Boston", "z - Anaheim", "y - Colorado", "x - St. Louis",  DIV  GP   W   L   OT   P   ROW   GF   GA   Diff    Home    Away   S/O 
1 1                                                                 p - Boston   A   82  54  19    9 117    51  261  177    +84  31-7-3 23-12-6   3-6
2 2                                                                z - Anaheim   P   82  54  20    8 116    51  266  209    +57  29-8-4 25-12-4   3-6
3 3                                                               y - Colorado   C   82  52  22    8 112    47  250  220    +30 26-11-4 26-11-4   5-4
4 4                                                              x - St. Louis   C   82  52  23    7 111    43  248  191    +57  28-9-4 24-14-3   9-3
5 5                                                               x - San Jose   P   82  51  22    9 111    41  249  200    +49  29-7-5 22-15-4  10-7
6 6                                                             y - Pittsburgh   M   82  51  24    7 109    44  249  207    +42  28-9-4 23-15-3   7-3
   L10   Streak 
1 5-2-3   Lost 1
2 7-2-1    Won 4
3 7-1-2     OT 1
4 3-7-0   Lost 6
5 5-4-1    Won 2
6 5-3-2     OT 2
```

Comment: I can get that too, but when I try to perform calculations on the columns, it does not work. ie > appStats[,4]-1
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(appStats[, 4], 1) : - not meaningful for factors

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as an argument to `readHTMLTable`